# Cmake generator expressions

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying for long time to understand the benefit of [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)  such as `$<xxx:yy>` in CMake, when and how  to use them.
Can anybody explain it clearly with some examples.
Many thank in advance

Comment: `Can anybody explain it clearly` - too broad. Should someone repeat [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)? Or other manual? Otherwise, explain **what exactly** you don't understand, e.g. which expression, or which example.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added the documentation of the part, that I didn't understand

Comment: `$<xxx:yy>` is nearly a half of all usage of generator expressions. Its meaning in short: if generator expression `xxx` is evaluated to TRUE (as boolean), then value of generator expression `yy` is used. Otherwise, empty string is used. Usefullness of this kind of expression is: when value of the left generator expressions depends on configuration option, and build system supports multiconfiguration (e.g. Visual Studio), then such expression cannot be rewritten with `if`, as concrete configuration isn't known at this stage.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

CMake does first parse the `CMakeLists.txt` files in your project - named "Configuration Phase" - and then it generates your build environment - named "Generation Phase".

So basically the generator expressions are for everything only the generator could know:

- The name and path of target outputs (mainly when cross-compiling and in multi-configuration environments)
- Or more generally any target property that the generator evaluates to mingle together the compiler/linker calls

Here are examples where I use generator expressions in my project:

1. Copying files next to the executable (in multi-configuration environments you can't just use variables like `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`)

   ```
   add_custom_command(
       TARGET library1 
       POST_BUILD
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
           "$<TARGET_FILE:library1>"
           "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:mainProject>/$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:library1>"
   )
   ```

   [CMake post-build-event: copy compiled libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696990/cmake-post-build-event-copy-compiled-libraries)

   ```
   add_custom_command(
       TARGET myBinary 
       POST_BUILD
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy  
                        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myTest.txt" 
                        "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:myBinary>/myTest.txt"
   )
   ```

   [how do I add external test files to a cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007428/how-do-i-add-external-test-files-to-a-cmake-project)
2. Differentiate e.g. `DEBUG` or `RELEASE` configurations

   ```
   add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/MDd>")
   ```

   [For Cmake, can you modify the release/debug compiler flags with `add_compiler_flags()` command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829152/for-cmake-can-you-modify-the-release-debug-compiler-flags-with-add-compiler-fl)

   [Modern way to set compiler flags in cross-platform cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955272/modern-way-to-set-compiler-flags-in-cross-platform-cmake-project)
3. With the `TARGET_PROPERTY` generator expression you could do a lot of things e.g.

   ```
   file(GENERATE 
       OUTPUT "includes.txt" 
       CONTENT "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:motor,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>\n"
   )
   ```

   [CMake doesn't pick up INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of linked library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091287/cmake-doesnt-pick-up-interface-include-directories-of-linked-library)

Comment: In 1 you're saying that "in multi-configuration environments you can't just use variables like `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`", why?